# jqgrid pagination server and client side

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to build my jqgrid a pagination system that will be in the client side and also in the server side . by that i mean that i want to take from the server lets say 100 records each time , and then i want my client side to manage a pagination to show only 10 records each page. when i reach to the 100 record , the server side will be triggered and will give the client side the next 100 records.

how can this be implemented ?  i'm kind of confused about this issue.

any help will be appritiated,

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: You try to make simple things too complex. **Why** you need so complex behavior? You should either use client side paging or server side paging and not a strange mix from the both.

Comment: Agreed. Why do you need to 2 levels of pagination instead of the standard jqGrid paginator?

Comment: We are  currently migrating form grid based on dhtmlx javascript components.
This grid allows us to load X amount of records and show only Y amount.
Pagination is done locally until the grid reaches the last record loaded.
Then the grid will load the next X amount of records.
Does this functionality exist in jqgrid ?

Comment: @user590586: The pagination like you want is not exit in jqGrid. The corresponding implementation will have many technical problems. The explanation could be relatively long. I strictly recommend you use standard server based data paging. It will save you many days of custoization and elimination of different side effects. Moreover if you write a comment to another comment you should use prefix like "@Oleg" (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 1):

A project I was working on had a requirement to do this.  We were able to implement a pretty robust solution.  When specifying the datatype for the jqgrid one of the options is a custom function that retrieves the data.  We used some closure magic to create a function that could keep track of state of the paging buffer.  We took care to support most of the config options for jqgrid and our function would get its configuration from the grid config.  We also looked at the jqgrid code so that we executed supported events properly.  The really cool thing that we were able to do was support a preload scheme for paging.  On the first request we would retrieve a large amount of records (in our case it was 300).  When the user had paged through 2/3 (200 records) of the data then we would retrieve the 1/3 of the original set(100 records), add them to the end of the buffer and remove the same amount from the front.  This preloading worked the same paging forwards or backwards.

Comment: Exactly as I would have approached it. Doesn't seem to be a simple task though. And I wouldn't want a built-in support for anything like this in a standard jqGrid: lots of code, rarely demanded functionality. But good to know, that it is possible to implement as an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

if your using ASP.net then google IPagedList JQGrid

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/15/38212/